# How to convert vsdx file to xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visio

I want to convert `.vsdx` file to `.xml` file, I search for it in msdn and related question but didn;t found any answer. can anyone give me link or piece of code ?

Comment: I believe vsdx files are ZIP files, just like i.e. docx. Unzip it using your favourite zipping tool and you'll probably end up with an XML somewhere.

Comment: does google not work in your neck of the country where you are at..? how come I was able to find this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/JJ228622.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [Microsoft](https://blogs.office.com/2012/09/10/vsdx-the-new-visio-file-format/):

> Office 2007 introduced new XML-based file formats for Microsoft Office Excel 2007, Office Word 2007, and Office PowerPoint 2007. Their file formats were the combination of a ZIP archive package and mainly XML content. Given the success of these formats, we decided to move in the same direction.
>
> You can think of the new VSDX format as being composed of two concepts: a ZIP archive package and XML content. First, we used the same ZIP archive package as used in Excel, Word, and PowerPoint. Formally, this package is defined by the Open Packaging Conventions (ISO/IEC 29500-2:2008) standard. Second, we based the XML content on our existing Visio XML Drawing (VDX) format.

In other words, vsdx already is a xml-file, you just have to unzip it, no convertion needed

Answer (score 0):

Well, (vsdx already is an xml file) that's the theory.  UnZipping a *.vsdx file yields a well-obfuscated result, courtesy of our friends in Redmond, including the following child folders:

- docProps;
- visio.

The `visio` folder includes the following child folders:
-- masters;
-- pages;
-- themes.

All folders, excluding the `themes` folder have the following child folder:

- _rels.